# Expression Blend does not list my application's objects in CLR objects

Tags: data-binding, expression-blend

I'm following a video tutorial on data binding with Visual Studio / Expression Blend.
In the tutorial the application's custom objects are listed when the presenter clicks on the "+CLR Object" button, but in when I do it, my application's objects are not listed.

What do I need to do to get my application's objects to be listed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a reference between the projects?  Seems like the child project is just missing a reference to the parent so they can be picked up.

Comment: Nice, that was it. I put a reference from LinkManagerApplication.Web to LinkManagerApplication and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You also need to make sure that if you are using parameterised constructors that your object also has a default constructor - this problem drove me a bit mad until I realised this.

```
public class MyThing{

private int _item;

//If this is the only constructor Expression does not show it up
public MyThing(int item){
   _item = item;
}

//Expression will only list your object if you add this constructor 
//when you also have parameterised constructors

public MyThing(){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.   I did not make the classes in my C# code public.

I had this:

class MyClass

needed this:

public class MyClass